# Ubuntu 12.10 live Using Grub

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2

someone can tell me how to boot Ubuntu 12.10 from Grub, I tried a lot but still getting error message `Cannot mount (hdx,msdosx)/ubuntu.iso`.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace hdx with the partition that contain the file.
Eg: hd0 if the file is in the first partition. Replace x with 0,1,2,3 to match the partition that contain the iso file

```
(hd0)   /dev/sda
(hd1)   /dev/sdb
(hd2)   /dev/sdc
```

And for msdosx, replace it with msdos1, it should work.

Last, you must copy the iso to the root of the device and rename it to ubuntu.iso

Comment: i entered x as a variable,its not what i did enter in my grub configuration, actually my drive was hd0,msdos1 and unfortunately it didn't work well for me.